# Joint distributions, marginal probability, probability theory (low level question)

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you have some $f(x,y),x \geq 0, y \geq 0$, and want to find the probability that at least one of the variables X and Y is above some number a.

Would it be correct to say that you could do this?
$$\int_a^\infty f_X(x) dx + \int_a^\infty f_Y(y) dy - \int_a^\infty \int_a^\infty f(x,y) dx dy$$

Since the marginal probability will count "both variables above a" twice?

My thoughts are: $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

, where A: "X is above a", and B: "Y is above a".

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that concludes the question.